# Which multithreading framework to use

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithreading and i would like to implement multithreading to an enterprise application. The problem is i have come across two(2) multithreading frameworks

1. Executor framework(Java 1.6)
2. Join/Fork framework(Java 1.7)

What are the pros and cons i should know before deciding on one, and start to learn and use.

Comment: Fork/join is for multithreaded problems which lend themselves to... forking and joining, i.e. where you can subdivide a big task into subtasks. Not all problems do.

Comment: Those are not frameworks for multithreading.  They are frameworks for solving different kinds of problems, and they happen to _use_ multithreading.  Except for homework assignments, making a program use threads should never be your goal.  It is merely something that you sometimes have to do in order to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executor framework is used when your application has some requirement where you have to execute the tasks by multiple threads concurrently, So If you use executor framework, then you don't need to manage the threads, you can just define the no. of threads to be in thread pool,and that's it.

Fork and Join framework, It is basically used when you have some sort of task(or algorithm) that you can sub-divide the tasks and then later join them to get the final result. It basically works on *Divide and conquer principle*. Example is- Merge sort,we can use fork join framework here.

Fork and Join framework is again a special  kind of thread pool(thread pools are already introduced in Executors framework.)

See below links to get your answers and clear your doubts:

1. [Executor framework and it working](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/java-executor-framework-tutorial-and-best-practices/)
2. [When to use executor framework](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)
3. [Fork and Join framework](http://howtodoinjava.com/java-7/forkjoin-framework-tutorial-forkjoinpool-example/)